# Add session variables for multiple users

Tags: php, sql, authentication, session-variables

I have a login page which directs to a process_login page which in turn directs the user to the appropriate page(i.e. i have a SQL table with 3 users - admin, student, instructor)

The code below achieves that but i am having difficulty when i try to add session variables. I have commented out the code i was trying when adding the session variables.

What would be the best way to add session variables to this?

process_login

```
  <?php
    //session_start();

    include('connect.php');
    $name =$_POST['userlogin'];
    $pass = $_POST['userpw'];

    //$_SESSION['currentuser'] = $name;

    $loginsql = "SELECT * FROM VLE_users WHERE name = '$name' AND passw = '$pass' ";

    $result = $conn -> query ($loginsql);


    if(!$result) {
        echo $conn ->error;

    }

    //$num = $result -> num_rows;


    //if($num>0){

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            //$userid =$row ['id'];
            //$S_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;


    if($row['type'] == 3){
        header('Location:index2.php');

    }elseif($row['type'] == 2){
        header('Location: studentpage.php');

    }elseif($row['type']==1){
        header('Location:admin_dash.php');

    }else{
        header('Location:index.php');

    }

        }


?>
```

Comment: What kind of trouble are you having? Your first 2 uses appear to be correct and the 3rd one has a typo (extra `S` in the name).

Comment: whe i uncomment that code, nothing works, cant login to any page.

Comment: If you fix the typo on the 3rd instance and uncomment them all do things work? If you haven't already enable error reporting so you can see what is going on `ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION["currentuser"] = $name;
```

Should work just fine

```
$S_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
```

Should be :

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
```

did you make a typo there or? And exactly what is the trouble you are experiencing? what doesn't work ?

Comment: yes typo.  when i uncomment the code i cant login to any page

Comment: it just takes me back to login page